# Does sharing one instance of ViewModel among several Views have any merits?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

One of my collegues offers quite a strange approach where VMs are used like singletons and each is attached simultaneously to several views.
I see no pros for such weirdness besides a kind of data sharing instead of caching at data access layer.
I've never seen this in practice but don't want to reject the ideas just because of that.

P.S. I speak about sharing one instance, not about applying differen views to one VM.

Thanks.

Comment: when people start doing such things it is always interesting to ask them where they see the advantages of such an approach or also, to what aim they are doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I would necessarily call it a "singleton" view model, but I like to share view model instances between multiple view controls in some cases. For example, this can be quite useful in a master/detail scenario where changes you make to the details may change the way the master part looks visually. For example, a list/tree view with an editing panel beside it that shows details of the selected item. Sure, you could do this kind of thing by passing messages between two VMs, but *that* seems more likely to add additional code than VM re-use.

Where I wouldn't recommend having a completely singleton VM is if you need some kind of master/detail scenario where the detail editing is modal, as in a dialog you open to make changes. There you are going to want to encapsulate the edit in a separate instance to make cancel support easier. An application-global (e.g. static) singleton implementation just makes that kind of thing much messier.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this approach could be useful if the views were to be kept in sync and made to look identical. Otherwise, I agree that it's confusing.

The only time I've seen singleton view models used in the real world are when you have a view that is also single instance, meaning that only one copy of the view is allowed to be open at any given time. In that case, there is a performance benefit because the view model doesn't have to be recreated every time the view is re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you must have a View Model for each view, but I think that in some cases may be useful use tha same view model for different views. For instance, supose you are displaying a User in differents application´s places and you want that when the User.Name changed in an application´s place, also in all other places where the User is showed, the User.Name changed too. For this notification issues, it is better have only one view model, then using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface all views will be notified. I think that this is what your collegue would may want, but also is not good make an over use of this, because would increase the complexity of the application, and/or may bring some unexpected behaviors.

Comment: I guess he really means what you say. But we earlier decided to use messenger from MVVM Ligh to keep VM's in sync. No we are trying to make our VMs reusable and dynamically switchable but that is another story.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Mvvm Light messenger is a good alternative, BUT, you need be careful with this too. An over use of the messenger can make very complex the application due to many class registrations, and also you need to unregister tha classes when done.